# Using the tf.Dataset API with Keras

Tags: keras

I am trying to use the Dataset API along with Keras and I am trying to use the third option in the action plan mentioned [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7503). Also I assumed that the third option was already done when seeing the second comment by @fchollet [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10110).

But then when I tried to implement it, I got the following error:

> When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect the tensors to have
> a static batch size. Got tensor with shape: `(None, 32, 64, 64, 3)`

I used the following strategy to fit the model:

```py
training_filenames = [.....]
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(training_filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function_all) # Parse the record into tensors.

dataset = dataset.batch(20)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
videos, labels= iterator.get_next()

model = create_base_network(input_shape = ( 32, 64, 64 3))
# output dimension will be (None, 10) for the model above

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)

model.fit(videos, labels, , epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=1000)
```

I can solve the problem by using `fit_generator`. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135499/how-to-properly-combine-tensorflows-dataset-api-and-keras) I applied @Dat-Nguyen's solution. But then I wasn't able to access the validation dataset within the custom callback in order to compute the AUC metric for example. So I need to use `fit` instead of `fit_generator`, but first need to git rid of this error.

So can anyone tell me why I got this error? Is the third step of fitting the model working now in Keras or does it still have issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I discovered the problem. I am using standalone Keras, not the one imported from Tensorflow. The new feature of feeding the iterator directly to `model.fit()` is valid only when you are using tf.Keras, not standalone Keras.

Answer (score 0):

so I figured out how to use keras with tf.DatasetAPI but without validation data. You can check out my question here [Keras model.fit() with tf.dataset API iterator initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50955798/keras-model-fit-with-tf-dataset-api-iterator-initializers)