# TensorFlow 2.0 Keras: How to write image summaries for TensorBoard

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard, summary

I'm trying to setup an image recognition CNN with TensorFlow 2.0. To be able to analyze my image augmentation I'd like to see the images I feed into the network in tensorboard.

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out, how to do this with TensorFlow 2.0 and Keras. I also didn't really find documentation on this.

For simplicity, I'm showing the code of an MNIST example. How would I add the image summary here?

```
import tensorflow as tf
(x_train, y_train), _ = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

def scale(image, label):
    return tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0, label

def augment(image, label):
    return image, label  # do nothing atm

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
dataset = dataset.map(scale).map(augment).batch(32)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(dataset, epochs=5, callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='D:\\tmp\\test')])
```

Comment: Does the code you have posted work with the older version of TF ?

Comment: Yes, the code also runs with TF 1.13.1. However, the image summary is not in the code, since I don't know how to add it.

Comment: You could try to put [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50955798/keras-model-fit-with-tf-dataset-api-validation-data) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784921/how-to-display-custom-images-in-tensorboard-using-keras?noredirect=1#comment85726690_43784921) together for a possible solution. But when I tried using tf 1.x it wasn't straightforward.

Comment: Here is a documentation about Tensorboard to use with TF 2.0 for Image data: [Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/r2/image_summaries)

Comment: @TobiasM.: I don't see how I can use the callbacks to get create the summary of the input images of the model. Can you go into more detail? The documentation does not give such an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Except providing an answer to your question 
I will make the code more `TF2.0`-like. If you have any questions/need clarification, please post a comment down below.

## 1. Loading data

I would advise to use [Tensorflow Datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets) library. There is absolutely no need to load data in `numpy` and transform it to `tf.data.Dataset` if one can do it in a single line:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

dataset = tfds.load("mnist", as_supervised=True, split=tfds.Split.TRAIN)
```

Line above will only return `TRAIN` split (read more about those [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/splits)).

## 2. Define Augmentations and Summaries

In order to save images, one has to keep [tf.summary.SummaryWriter](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/summary/SummaryWriter) object throughout each pass.

I have created a convenient wrapping class with `__call__` method for easy usage with `tf.data.Dataset`'s `map` capabilities:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class ExampleAugmentation:
    def __init__(self, logdir: str, max_images: int, name: str):
        self.file_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)
        self.max_images: int = max_images
        self.name: str = name
        self._counter: int = 0

    def __call__(self, image, label):
        augmented_image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(
            tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image)
        )
        with self.file_writer.as_default():
            tf.summary.image(
                self.name,
                augmented_image,
                step=self._counter,
                max_outputs=self.max_images,
            )

        self._counter += 1
        return augmented_image, label
```

`name` will be the name under which each part of images will be saved. Which part you may ask - the part defined by `max_outputs`.

Say `image` in `__call__` will have shape `(32, 28, 28, 1)`, where the first dimension is batch, second width, third height and last channels (in case of MNIST only onel but this dimension is needed in `tf.image` augmentations). Furthermore, let's say `max_outputs` is specified as `4`. In this case, only 4 first images from batch will be saved. Default value is `3`, so you may set it as `BATCH_SIZE` to save every image.

In `Tensorboard`, each image will be a separate sample over which you can iterate at the end.

`_counter` is needed so the images **will not** be overwritten (I think, not really sure, clarification from someone else would be nice).

**Important:** You may want to rename this class to something like `ImageSaver` when doing more serious buisness and move augmentation to separate functors/lambda functions. It suffices for presentation purposes I guess.

## 3. Setup global variables

**Please do not mix function declaration, global variables, data loading and others** (like loading data and creating function afterwards). I know `TF1.0` encouraged this type of programming but they are trying to get away from it and you might want to follow the trend.

Below I have defined some global variables which will be used throughout next parts, pretty self-explanatory I guess:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 32
DATASET_SIZE = 60000
EPOCHS = 5

LOG_DIR = "/logs/images"
AUGMENTATION = ExampleAugmentation(LOG_DIR, max_images=4, name="Images")
```

## 4. Dataset augmentation

Similar to yours but with a little twist:

```
dataset = (
    dataset.map(
        lambda image, label: (
            tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32),
            label,
        )
    )
    .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    .map(AUGMENTATION)
    .repeat(EPOCHS)
)
```

- `repeat` is needed as the loaded dataset is a generator
- [`tf.image.convert_image_dtype`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/image/convert_image_dtype) - better and more readable option than explicit `tf.cast` mixed with division by `255` (and ensures proper image format)
- batching done before augmentation just for the sake of presentation

## 5. Define model, compile, train

Almost as you did in your example, but I have provided additional `steps_per_epoch`, so `fit` knows how many batches constitute an epoch:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"),
    ]
)

model.compile(
    optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]
)
model.fit(
    dataset,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    steps_per_epoch=DATASET_SIZE // BATCH_SIZE,
    callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=LOG_DIR)],
)
```

Not much to explain other than that I think.

## 6. Run Tensorboard

Since `TF2.0` one can do it inside colab using `%tensorboard --logdir /logs/images`, just wanted to add this for others who may visit this issue. Do it however you like, anyways you know how to do it for sure.

Images should be inside `IMAGES` and each sample named by `name` provided to `AUGMENTATION` object.

## 7. Whole code (to make everyone's life easier)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds


class ExampleAugmentation:
    def __init__(self, logdir: str, max_images: int, name: str):
        self.file_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)
        self.max_images: int = max_images
        self.name: str = name
        self._counter: int = 0

    def __call__(self, image, label):
        augmented_image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(
            tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image)
        )
        with self.file_writer.as_default():
            tf.summary.image(
                self.name,
                augmented_image,
                step=self._counter,
                max_outputs=self.max_images,
            )

        self._counter += 1
        return augmented_image, label


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Global settings

    BATCH_SIZE = 32
    DATASET_SIZE = 60000
    EPOCHS = 5

    LOG_DIR = "/logs/images"
    AUGMENTATION = ExampleAugmentation(LOG_DIR, max_images=4, name="Images")

    # Dataset

    dataset = tfds.load("mnist", as_supervised=True, split=tfds.Split.TRAIN)

    dataset = (
        dataset.map(
            lambda image, label: (
                tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32),
                label,
            )
        )
        .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
        .map(AUGMENTATION)
        .repeat(EPOCHS)
    )

    # Model and training

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
        [
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"),
        ]
    )

    model.compile(
        optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]
    )
    model.fit(
        dataset,
        epochs=EPOCHS,
        steps_per_epoch=DATASET_SIZE // BATCH_SIZE,
        callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=LOG_DIR)],
    )
```

Comment: Is it recommended to install tensorflow_datasets or is it the same as using tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()  provided by the tensorflow module?

Comment: `tensorflow_datasets` returns `tf.data.Dataset` object which allows you to preprocess your data easier. `numpy` is not Tensorflow oriented. You can't use stuff like `map` or `cache` with plain arrays, so I would stick to `tf.data.Dataset` class at least.

Comment: A typo: "... as to keep tf.summar(y).SummaryWriter ..."

Comment: thanks for the example, very helpful. when I run this, all of the images show up in step 0, and running with more epochs doesn't produce more images logged to the tensorboard. is the counter not being incremented?

Comment: @AlexShepard it should be and was when I last checked IIRC. If you find out why please comment on this answer, I will check it when I have more time.

Comment: @AlexShepard, have you found out how to fix this problem? I am also having all show up in step 0, and running with more epochs doesn't produce more images logged to the tensorboard.

I don't think the counter is not implemented, because the images do not change at all, it seems like only the image with counter 0 is written, and then nothing...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to add input image to tensorboard

```
def scale(image, label):
    return tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0, label


def augment(image, label):
    return image, label  # do nothing atm


file_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir + "/images")


def plot_to_image(figure):
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
    plt.close(figure)
    buf.seek(0)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(buf.getvalue(), channels=4)
    image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
    return image


def image_grid():
    """Return a 5x5 grid of the MNIST images as a matplotlib figure."""
    # Create a figure to contain the plot.
    figure = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    for i in range(25):
        # Start next subplot.
        plt.subplot(5, 5, i + 1, title=str(y_train[i]))
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
        plt.grid(False)
        image, _ = scale(x_train[i], y_train[i])
        plt.imshow(x_train[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)

    return figure


# Prepare the plot
figure = image_grid()
# Convert to image and log
with file_writer.as_default():
    tf.summary.image("Training data", plot_to_image(figure), step=0)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
dataset = dataset.map(scale).map(augment).batch(32)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(dataset, epochs=5, callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)])
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer my question at all. I asked how I can show the input images fed into my network. I already found this example, but it only shows an arbitray other image instead of the images fed into the network.

Comment: I've updated the code to add summary in tensorboard

Comment: Thx, for your effort! But I don't want to simply write the first 25 images to tensorboard. Instead I want to write the summary during training, so I can see examples of the actual images fed into the network. E.g. if I apply data augmentation, I want to track the images the network actually gets to see during the whole training. With standard tensorflow this wasn't a problem. I wonder how I can do this with keras and TF 2.0.