# How to use Keras generator with tf.data API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to use the generator found in Keras preprocessing library. I wanted to experiment with this since Keras provides great functions for image augmentation. However, I am not sure if this is actually possible.

Here is how I made a tf dataset from the Keras generator:

```
def make_generator():
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
    train_generator = 
    train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dataset_folder,target_size=(224, 224), class_mode='categorical', batch_size=32)
    return train_generator

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(make_generator,(tf.float32, tf.float32)).shuffle(64).repeat().batch(32)
```

Note that if you try to directly give `train_generator` as the argument to `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` there will be an error. However, the above method doesn't produce an error.

When I run it within a session to check the output from the dataset I get the following error.

```
iterator = train_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
sess = tf.Session()
for i in range(100):
    sess.run(next_element)
```

> Found 1000 images belonging to 2 classes.
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in _do_call(self, fn, *args)    1291     try:
>   -> 1292       return fn(*args)    1293     except errors.OpError as e:
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata) 
>   1276       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
>   -> 1277           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)    1278
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
>   target_list, run_metadata)    1366         self._session, options,
>   feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
>   -> 1367         run_metadata)    1368
>
> InvalidArgumentError: Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in
>   component 0. First element had shape [32,224,224,3] and element 29 had
>   shape [8,224,224,3].   [[{{node IteratorGetNext_2}} =
>   IteratorGetNextoutput_shapes=[, ],
>   output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Please let me know if anyone has any experience with this or know any alternate way.

**UPDATE**

I was able to solve the problem after using the suggestion by J.E.K.

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(make_generator,(tf.float32, tf.float32))
```

However when I give `train_dataset` to a Keras `.fit` method I get the following error.

```
model_regular.fit(train_dataset,steps_per_epoch=1000,epochs=2)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 model_regular.fit(train_dataset,steps_per_epoch=1000,epochs=2)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py
>   in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
>   validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
>   sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
>   **kwargs)    1507         steps_name='steps_per_epoch',    1508         steps=steps_per_epoch,
>   -> 1509         validation_split=validation_split)    1510     1511     # Prepare validation data.
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py
>   in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight,
>   batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split)
>       948           x = self._dataset_iterator_cache[x]
>       949         else:
>   --> 950           iterator = x.make_initializable_iterator()
>       951           self._dataset_iterator_cache[x] = iterator
>       952           x = iterator
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py
>   in make_initializable_iterator(self, shared_name)
>       119     with ops.colocate_with(iterator_resource):
>       120       initializer = gen_dataset_ops.make_iterator(self._as_variant_tensor(),
>   --> 121                                                   iterator_resource)
>       122     return iterator_ops.Iterator(iterator_resource, initializer,
>       123                                  self.output_types, self.output_shapes,
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py
>   in make_iterator(dataset, iterator, name)    2542   if _ctx is None or
>   not _ctx._eager_context.is_eager:    2543     _, _, _op =
>   _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
>   -> 2544         "MakeIterator", dataset=dataset, iterator=iterator, name=name)    2545     return _op    2546     _result = None
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py
>   in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
>       348       # Need to flatten all the arguments into a list.
>       349       # pylint: disable=protected-access
>   --> 350       g = ops._get_graph_from_inputs(_Flatten(keywords.values()))
>       351       # pylint: enable=protected-access
>       352     except AssertionError as e:
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
>   in _get_graph_from_inputs(op_input_list, graph)    5659         graph
>   = graph_element.graph    5660       elif original_graph_element is not None:
>   -> 5661         _assert_same_graph(original_graph_element, graph_element)    5662       elif graph_element.graph is not graph:
>   5663         raise ValueError("%s is not from the passed-in graph." %
>   graph_element)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
>   in _assert_same_graph(original_item, item)    5595   if
>   original_item.graph is not item.graph:    5596     raise
>   ValueError("%s must be from the same graph as %s." % (item,
>   -> 5597                                                                 original_item))    5598     5599
>
> ValueError: Tensor("IteratorV2:0", shape=(), dtype=resource) must be
>   from the same graph as Tensor("FlatMapDataset:0", shape=(),
>   dtype=variant).

Is this a bug or is Keras fit method not meant to be used this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Properly Combine TensorFlow's Dataset API and Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135499/how-to-properly-combine-tensorflows-dataset-api-and-keras)

Comment: Regarding why you need to pass `make_generator` rather than `train_generator`, the [docs explain it](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_python_generators): "The constructor takes a callable as input, not an iterator. This allows it to restart the generator when it reaches the end. It takes an optional args argument, which is passed as the callable's arguments."

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to reproduce your results with a simple example and I found out that you get different output shapes when one uses batching within the generator function and `tf.data`.

The Keras function `train_datagen.flow_from_directory(batch_size=32)` already returns the data with shape `[batch_size, width, height, depth]`. If one uses `tf.data.Dataset().batch(32)` the output data is batched again into shape `[batch_size, batch_size, width, height, depth]`.

This could have caused your issue for some reason.

Comment: Thank, you for the suggestion. It works and I able to get out output. However, when I feed train_dataset to model.fit(), it gives another error. I will update the original post with the new error.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't

```
model_regular.fit(train_dataset,steps_per_epoch=1000,epochs=2)
```

be

```
model_regular.fit(train_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator(),steps_per_epoch=1000,epochs=2)
```

as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48134765/3387851).