# tf.data.Dataset from tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, marshalling

How do I create a [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) from [`tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.8/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory)?

I'm considering [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator), but it's unclear how to acquire the `output_types` keyword argument for it, given the return type:

> A `DirectoryIterator` yielding tuples of `(x, y)` where `x` is a numpy array containing a batch of images with shape `(batch_size, *target_size, channels)` and `y` is a numpy array of corresponding labels.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both [batch_x](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L1351) and [batch_y](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L1383) in `ImageDataGenerator` are of type `K.floatx()`, so must be `tf.float32` by default.

Similar question was discussed already at [How to use Keras generator with tf.data API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636127/how-to-use-keras-generator-with-tf-data-api). Let me copy-paste the answer from there:

```
def make_generator():
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
    train_generator = 
    train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dataset_folder,target_size=(224, 224), class_mode='categorical', batch_size=32)
    return train_generator

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(make_generator,(tf.float32, tf.float32))
```

The author faced another issue with the graph scope, but I guess it is unrelated to your question.

Or as a one liner:

```
tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda:
    ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory('folder_path'),(tf.float32, tf.float32))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is giving me an error: 'TypeError: `generator` must be callable.'.   `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory('folder_path'), (tf.float32, tf.float32))`

Comment: Try `train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(make_generator(), ...`

Comment: I did not quite understand how to fill `train_generator =` part. can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @ Dmytro Prylipko In my case it does manage to transform it to a     Dataset    type, but the dimension are    <unknown>    . Yet i've use exactly the same structure as above.

Answer (score 7):

Here is my solution. To show how it works, I use cats/dogs datasets:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf


_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/cats_and_dogs_filtered.zip'
path_to_zip = tf.keras.utils.get_file('cats_and_dogs.zip', origin=_URL, extract=True)
PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path_to_zip), 'cats_and_dogs_filtered')

train_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'train')
#'/Users/mustafamuratarat/.keras/datasets/cats_and_dogs_filtered/train'

BATCH_SIZE = 32
IMG_SIZE = (160, 160)

img_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

gen = img_gen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, target_size=(160, 160), batch_size=32)
#<tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator at 0x7fb9fde3b250>

#gen.class_indices
#{'cats': 0, 'dogs': 1}

#gen.target_size
#(160, 160)

# gen.batch_size
# 32

# gen.num_classes
# 2

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: gen,
    output_types = (tf.float32, tf.float32),
    output_shapes = ([None, 160, 160, 3], [None, 2]),
)

#list(dataset.take(1).as_numpy_iterator())
```

Then you can feed `dataset` object to any model.

Comment: Good to see `output_shapes` and `output_types` set on `from_generator`… might work better as a comment or edit of the other answer though, with commentary on the relative advantage