# How can a generator (ImageDataGenerator) run out of data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Lets start with a *folder containing 1000 images*.

Now if we use *no generator* and `batch_size = 10` and `steps_per_epoch = 100` we will have used every picture as *10 * 100 = 1000*. So increasing `steps_per_epoche` will (rightfully) result in the error:

> tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 10000 batches)

On the other hand using *a generator* will result in endless batches of images:

```py
datagenerator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.1,
    zoom_range=0.1,
    # ...
)

imageFlow = datagenerator.flow_from_directory(
        image_dir_with_1000_pcs,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=10,
        class_mode='binary')

i = 0
for x, y in imageFlow:
  print(x.shape) # batch of images
  
  i += 1
  if i > 3000:
    break # I break, because it ENDLESSLY goes on otherwise
```

But still, if I go and run

```py
history = model.fit(
      imageFlow,
      steps_per_epoch=101, # I increased this above 100!
      epochs=5,
      #...
)
```

I will get the same error: WHY? `model.fit()` gets a generator and therefore endless batches. How can it run out of data when being fed endless batches?

Before posting this question, I read:

- documentation like [TensorFlow ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory) and
- relative SO questions like [Keras Data Augmentation with ImageDataGenerator (Your input ran out of data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65661950/keras-data-augmentation-with-imagedatagenerator-your-input-ran-out-of-data)

Comment: Was also expecting endless supply with data augmentation. I guess the implementation changed to ```Dataset```. Did you find a workaround? I was looking for it to loop over again with data augmentation.

Comment: Sorry, but I can not help you here, as I was only looking for an explanation to the behavior that I did not expect. But I think you do not need to workaround this as with each epoche you get differently augmented data. Therefore endless epoches == endless augmented data if you will, or? Otherwise batches could be prepared beforehand which is a simple workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can a generator (ImageDataGenerator) run out of data?

As far as I know, it creates a `tf.data.Dataset` from the generator, which does not run infinitely, that's why you see this behaviour when fitting.

If it was an infinite dataset, then **you had to** specify `steps_per_epoch`.

**Edit**: If you don't specify `steps_per_epoch` then the training will stop when `number_of_batches >= len(dataset) // batch_size`. It is done in every epoch.

For to inspect what really happens under the hood you can check [the source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/007c56dff64b740be608aebebcf0c6be75252049/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L1464). As it can be seen a `tf.data.Dataset` is created and that handles batch and epoch iteration actually.

Comment: But the documentation at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#examples_2 states that "we need to break the loop by hand because [...] the generator loops indefinitely". Btw, getting a tf.data.Dataset is a task of its own - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54606302/tf-data-dataset-from-tf-keras-preprocessing-image-imagedatagenerator-flow-from-d

Comment: Yes that's how a generator works in TF. `model.fit()` handles the terminating process actually. If you want to create a manual traning process, then you have to handle the epoch endings etc. I meant under the hood it returns a tf.data.Dataset

Comment: Ok, to me a model asks for batches of data in each step. The batches can be endlessly delivered by a generator. And still the model runs out of data before ending the epoch. Why? There is no `len(imageFlow)`. It just goes on and on. Documentation on model.fit() even states "When passing an *infinitely repeating dataset*, you must specify the steps_per_epoch argument.".

Comment: I really sorry, but I can't follow the *length of a generator* part. Generators yield till active use of break, how could there be a length? Could you be so kind and may be try a different wording? I am really trying to get my head around it.

Comment: Sorry for cryptic comment I deleted it, edited the answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: Oh man, the source file helped to find the right place. Model.fit() actually calls `data_adapter.get_data_handler` with the small but important comment "Creates a `tf.data.Dataset` and [...]". They really do not use the generator, but put much effort in creating a tf.data.Dataset. It is even the prefered way to use Dataset. @Frightera I would rather like to see this source file https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/007c56dff64b740be608aebebcf0c6be75252049/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L1464 linked in the answer.

Comment: I edited the answer, however I thought keeping the some of the parts should be fine. Thank you for pointing an another line from source code. I'd happy if you can accept the answer.