# load tfrecord files into keras model by batch

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tfrecord

I want to load tfrecord extracted batch data in keras model

I used the tfrecord to store my data and its label, and I extracted it out using tf.dataset API by batch and created an iterator, but I dont know how to proceed to load data into keras model.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import keras as k
import numpy as np
num_epochs = 2
data_dim = 75
timesteps = 300
num_classes = 82
batch_size = 128
training_filename = [filepath]
validation_filename = [filepath]


def parse_function(example1):
    features = tf.io.parse_single_example(example1, features={
        'label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, default_value=None),
        'skeleton': tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=(), dtype=tf.string),
        'skeleton_shape': tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=(3,), dtype=tf.int64)})
    features['skeleton'] = tf.decode_raw(features['skeleton'], tf.float64)
    skeleton = tf.reshape(features['skeleton'], (300, 75))
    label = tf.one_hot(features['label'], num_classes, dtype=tf.float64)
    return skeleton, label


def load_dataset(filename):
    data_reading = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename)
    dataset = data_reading.map(parse_function)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    skeleton, label = iterator.get_next()
    return skeleton, label


x_train, y_train = load_dataset(training_filename)
x_val, y_val = load_dataset(validation_filename)

model = k.Sequential()
model.add(k.layers.LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(k.layers.LSTM(128, activation='relu'))

model.add(k.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          epochs=5, shuffle=True,
          validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/MScProject/extraction/feeder.py", line 60, in <module>
    y=run_model(x_train,y_train,x_val,y_val)
  File "D:\MScProject\extraction\lstm.py", line 22, in run_model
    validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
  File "C:\Users\wille\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 952, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\wille\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 677, in _standardize_user_data
    self._set_inputs(x)
  File "C:\Users\wille\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 589, in _set_inputs
    self.build(input_shape=(None,) + inputs.shape[1:])
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "TensorShape") to tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of TF are you using?

If you are with TF 2.0 you can feed directly tf.data.Dataset to `model.fit`.

Check this [entry](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras#input_tfdata_datasets) at TF documentation

Comment: tf 1.14, is there any way to do it in the current version?

Comment: Maybe this [notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/kmader/tf-data-tutorial-with-retina-and-keras) or this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135499/how-to-properly-combine-tensorflows-dataset-api-and-keras) can help you