# How to use Tensorflow 2 Dataset API with Keras?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow-datasets

This question has been answered for Tensorflow 1, eg: [How to Properly Combine TensorFlow's Dataset API and Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135499/how-to-properly-combine-tensorflows-dataset-api-and-keras), but this answer hasn't helped for my use case.

Below is an example of a model with three float32 inputs and one float32 output. I have a large amount of data that doesn't all fit into memory at once, so it's split into separate files. I'm trying to use the [Dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) to train a model by bringing in a portion of the training data at once.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
import numpy as np

# Create TF model of a given architecture (number of hidden layers, layersize, #outputs, activation function)
def create_model(h=2, l=64, activation='relu'):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        layers.Dense(l, activation=activation, input_shape=(3,), name='input_layer'),
        *[layers.Dense(l, activation=activation) for _ in range(h)],
        layers.Dense(1, activation='linear', name='output_layer')])
    return model

# Load data (3 X variables, 1 Y variable) split into 5 files
# (for this example, just create a list 5 numpy arrays)
list_of_training_datasets = [np.random.rand(10,4).astype(np.float32) for _ in range(5)]
validation_dataset = np.random.rand(30,4).astype(np.float32)

def data_generator():
    for data in list_of_training_datasets:
        x_data = data[:, 0:3]
        y_data = data[:, 3:4]
        yield((x_data,y_data))

# prepare model
model = create_model(h=2,l=64,activation='relu')
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())

# load dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator,(np.float32,np.float32))

# fit model
model.fit(dataset, epochs=100, validation_data=(validation_dataset[:,0:3],validation_dataset[:,3:4]))
```

Running this, I get the error:

> **ValueError: Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank.**

Does anyone know how to get this working? I would also like to be able to use the batch dimension, to load two data files at a time, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works, but I don't know if this is the most efficient.

As far as I understand, if your training dataset is split into 10 pieces, then you should set steps_per_epoch=10. This ensures that each epoch will step through all data once. As far as I understand, `dataset.repeat()` is needed because the dataset iterator is "used up" after the first epoch. `.repeat()` ensures that the iterator gets created again after being used up.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
import tensorflow as tf

# Create TF model of a given architecture (number of hidden layers, layersize, #outputs, activation function)
def create_model(h=2, l=64, activation='relu'):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        layers.Dense(l, activation=activation, input_shape=(3,), name='input_layer'),
        *[layers.Dense(l, activation=activation) for _ in range(h)],
        layers.Dense(1, activation='linear', name='output_layer')])
    return model

# Load data (3 X variables, 1 Y variable) split into 5 files
# (for this example, just create a list 5 numpy arrays)
list_of_training_datasets = [np.random.rand(10,4).astype(np.float32) for _ in range(5)]
steps_per_epoch = len(list_of_training_datasets)
validation_dataset = np.random.rand(30,4).astype(np.float32)

def data_generator():
    for data in list_of_training_datasets:
        x_data = data[:, 0:3]
        y_data = data[:, 3:4]
        yield((x_data,y_data))

# prepare model
model = create_model(h=2,l=64,activation='relu')
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())

# load dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator,output_types=(np.float32,np.float32),
                output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([None,3]), tf.TensorShape([None,1]))).repeat()

# fit model
model.fit(dataset.as_numpy_iterator(), epochs=10,steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
          validation_data=(validation_dataset[:,0:3],validation_dataset[:,3:4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to need to specify the shapes of the your dataset along with the return data types like this.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator,
                                         (np.float32,np.float32),
                                         ((None, 3), (None, 1)))
```

Comment: This results in the error "ValueError: `batch_size` or `steps` is required for `Tensor` or `NumPy` input data."

Then if I specify either batch_size=1 or steps=1 I get subsequent errors.

If I specify batch_size=1 I get the error "ValueError: The `batch_size` argument must not be specified for the given input type."

If I specify steps=1 I get the error "TypeError: Unrecognized keyword arguments: {'steps': 1}"